# gouping an observable collection for semantic zoom

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, uwp, observablecollection

I have an observable collection which is populated from an SQLite database, the data is then displayed in a list view. I want to change this to a semantic view with headers, How do I group the objects inside the collection?

XAML Page

```
<Page.Resources>
    <vm:IngredientsCollection x:Key="Ingredient"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <uwp:SwipeListView x:Name="IngredientList" ItemClick="ItemClicked" LayoutUpdated="ListUpdated" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Ingredient}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemSwipe="ItemSwipe" ItemLeftBackground="#FF007575" KeyDown="DeleteKeyPressed" IsTabStop="True" Margin="0,0,0,-1">
                <uwp:SwipeListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IngredientName}" FontSize="18" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IngredientCategory.CategoryName}" FontSize="16" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </uwp:SwipeListView.ItemTemplate>
        <uwp:SwipeListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="uwp:SwipeListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF007575"/>
            </Style>
        </uwp:SwipeListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </uwp:SwipeListView>
</Grid>
```

Observable Collection

```
    public class IngredientsCollection : ObservableCollection<Ingredient>
{

    public IngredientsCollection()

        : base()
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.path);
        var Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
        Ingredients = db.GetAllWithChildren<Ingredient>().ToList();


        foreach (var Ingredient in Ingredients)
        {
            Add(Ingredient);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905921/listview-keep-listviewheaderitem-on-top)?

Comment: yes that's the sort of thing I'm after

Answer (score 0):

To goup an observable collection for semantic zoom, we can use **[CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)** as the data source. And then use grouping LINQ query to set [CollectionViewSource.Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.source.aspx) property like what in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38909323/5506161).

```
List<TestDemo> list = new List<TestDemo>();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    list.Add(new TestDemo { Key = "A", Text = $"Test A {i}" });
    list.Add(new TestDemo { Key = "B", Text = $"Test B {i}" });
}

var result = from t in list group t by t.Key;

groupInfoCVS.Source = result;
```

Once we set the `CollectionViewSource`, we can then use it as [ItemsSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) of [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) or [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) to support grouping. For more info about [SemanticZoom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.semanticzoom.aspx), please see [Semantic zoom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/semantic-zoom), [Quickstart: adding SemanticZoom controls (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781234.aspx) and also the [UI basics (XAML) sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics) on GitHub.