# Keep ListView.Header anchored/sticky/frozen to top when scrolling

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, controls

How to keep the built-in `Header` of a `ListView` frozen to the top when scrolling vertically down through the `ListView` items?

**Before flagging as duplicate**: I tried to apply answers in [Keep ListView.HeaderTemplate visible/static/sticky in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513410) for Xamarin.Forms targeting Android without success.

Short code sample:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"             
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

    <ListView.Header>
        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               Text="Header Title"/>
    </ListView.Header>
                
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: The default listview does not support fix header in top in Android, have a look at [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72170/sticky-header-listview) may help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Maybe be it will be better that I move to a CollectionView

Comment: Yes, collectionview maybe a better choice.

Comment: But it won't save my issue for now I thought such feature has been implemented already in CollectionView but I was wrong https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8656

Comment: I saw there is a [sample project](https://github.com/xamcat/Scratch/tree/master/FormsStickyHeaders) there which implemented sticky headers.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I didn't make it to work maybe it targeting group header only, also it seems a bit complicated to be added in a project

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative approach to this if the list isn't long

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               Text="Header Title"/>
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <!-- boxview as separator -->
                        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="Aqua" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would like to see a solution based on the built-in Header of a ListView.

Answer (score -1):

Try to place the label outside the listview, it will be above the ListView regardless of scrolling:

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           Text="Header Title"/>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"             
      HasUnevenRows="True"
      SeparatorVisibility="Default"
      CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
      Margin="0,-5,0,0">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```